# How to use OTG cable in Motorola Moto G2?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, motorola-moto-g2

Recently, I purchased an OTG cable model S-K07 to use with my Moto G2 mobile. When I connected the OTG cable with 4GB pen drive, FAT32 formatted, it did not work.  After some time, the pen drive got heated up and I removed the pen drive from OTG cable.  When I plugged the pen drive into my laptop, it was not recognized by the computer.

How can I use the OTG cable with my mobile?

Answer (score 0):

The device should be visible to use on any file manager that supports OTG (eg. [Solid explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.solidexplorer2&hl=en)). If your flash drive is not usable anymore, maybe your otg cable, phone or flash drive has/had an issue and burnt the flash. Its usually plug and play unless its an ntfs partition, in which case if your OEM/file manager does not support it properly you may have issues.

Comment: "*maybe your otg cable, phone or flash drive has/had an issue and burnt the flash*" -- I'd like to see sources backing your claim (all should be related to Android).

Comment: _maybe_. I came to this conclusion because the OP stated that the flash drive got warm. IF you send power on signal line, it may burn the flash/NAND chip inside. A faulty, poorly engineered OTG cable, which are fairly common can have such issue.